# some of my static and dynamic images link is broken on live vps ubuntu server but working on local xampp server

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-18.04, vps

Some of my static and dynamic images links are broken on vps ubuntu server but working on local XAMPP server. When I try opening the images in a new tab using their url, it says *"404 not found Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."*  It appears that my paths are correct. See the below picture for the images in file manager on the vps server in `public_html`.

I have tried clearing cache and cookies, using several methods on forums and other methods too but still doesn't work.

*index.php*

```
<section id="service">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Our Products</h2>
            <br>
               <?php 
                    $select_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select *from products");
                   $row=mysqli_num_rows($select_query);
                ?>
            <div class="row">
             <?php if($row>0)
                {   
                    $sr=0;
                    while ($fetcharray=mysqli_fetch_array($select_query)) {
                    $sr+=1;
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" >
                    <div class="service_item" >
                        <div class="service_photo" style="height:370px; width: 320px";>
                           <a href="description.php?pid=<?php echo base64_encode($fetcharray['id']);?>"><img src="<?php echo $fetcharray['picture'];?>" alt="Program"  style="height:370px; width: 320px"; /> </a>
                            <!--<div class="photo_overlay"></div>-->                        
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="service_caption">
                            <h4><?php echo $fetcharray['name'];?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $fetcharray['price'];?><br><?php echo $fetcharray['quantity'];?><br><?php echo $fetcharray['description'];?></p>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }}?>
```

- [rendering of images on production Linux server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLcge.jpg)
- [rendering of images on local XAMP server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLys.jpg)
- [path in production Linux server file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKFlP.jpg)

Comment: What's the code and the rendered HTML? Not able to provide an answer to an issue without seeing the code causing the issue.

Comment: let me add it to the original post and thanks for help

Comment: http://www.musclehubnutrition.com/ url of website if you want to check it.

Comment: I am just a beginner in development. But the code is working perfectly fine on the local machine using xampp server also database is connected successfully on live server as well.

Comment: Your issue is caused by using Windows XAMPP server which file names are **not** case-sensitive and uploading to a Linux server which file names are case-sensitive. The source file referenced in the html is using `images/fitness.png` while the actual file location is `images/fitness.PNG`